# Does materialize function not work with tabular function argument in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I created a simple function MaterializeRemoteInputTable below which accepts the output of a table as an input.
To test if the input is materialized, I am using it twice to calculate two scalar values - x and y:

```
.create-or-alter function MaterializeRemoteInputTable(inputTable: (State:string)) {
let materializedInput = materialize(inputTable);
let x = toscalar(materializedInput | count );
let y = toscalar(materializedInput | where State contains "S" | count);
print x, y;
}
```

I am using the sample kusto database's function output as an input to the above function:

```
cluster('https://help.kusto.windows.net').database('Samples').
GetStatesWithPopulationSmallerThan(1000000)
| invoke MaterializeRemoteInputTable()
```

On querying the help.kusto.windows.net cluster with my ClientActivityId, I see two queries are executed:

```
.show commands-and-queries 
| where ClientActivityId contains "KE.RunQuery;<guid...>"

Above query outputs two rows:

GetStatesWithPopulationSmallerThan(long(1000000))|__executeAndCache|count as Count|limit long(1)|project ["b2fb..."]=["Count"]
GetStatesWithPopulationSmallerThan(long(1000000))|__executeAndCache|where (["State"] contains ("S"))|count as Count|limit long(1)|project ["5d0e2..."]=["Count"]
```

Since I have materialized the input to my MaterializeRemoteInputTable, why are two queries executed on the remote cluster, once each for x and y?

Comment: While I don't have the answer, I would claim that you have added to many lairs of complexity to your experiment.  The input to `MaterializeRemoteInputTable()` is a *function* invoked on a *remote cluster*. I wonder if you would get the same results for a local dataset?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I created a function returning a datatable: `.create function LocalDataset() { datatable(State:string) [ "SD", "CA" ] }`. For `LocalDataset() | invoke MaterializeRemoteInputTable()`, there is a single entry in the DB queries journal. Irrespective of whether the input function/table is remote or local, shouldn't materialize function in MaterializeRemoteInputTable cache the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no issue with materialize & tabular argument to a function.
The issue is a known limitation in materialize with cross cluster query that in some cases the materialization is not performed.
Please note that this is only a performance issue and not a logical issue (query results are guaranteed to be correct).

Comment: Thanks @Ziad! Could you please point me to the link where this limitation is documented? [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/materializefunction) does not document it.